# Django adding related fields in admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

Currently in my admin I have many excerpts in which admin users can create and then go into the "women" interface and attach the excerpt. Is it possible to add a selection field in the excerpt admin where the user could select which woman the excerpt belongs to rather than creating the excerpt and going into the "women" interface to create the relationship?

```
class Excerpt(models.Model):
  extract = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
  audio_url = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  start_time = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  end_time = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.extract

class Women(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, blank=True)
    excerpt = models.ManyToManyField(Excerpt, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can one Excerpt have multiple women associated to it ? because it seems to me like women can have multiple excerpt but not the other way around, you're therefore looking for a foreign key relation ship between women and excerpt models.

Comment: @scharette good point. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you change the relation that I pointed in the comments, you'll need to first delete the `manytomany` relationship in `Women` and then change your 
 `Excerpt` model a bit. What you want to do is have a foreign key in your `Excerpt` model to `Women` like that,

```
class Excerpt(models.Model):
    women = models.ForeignKey(Women, ...)
```

the other answer had the right approach but the wrong execution, here is the correct way of implementing inlines in your case,

```
class ExcerptInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Excerpt


class WomenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ExcerptInline]
```

You finally want to register the whole thing,

```
admin.site.register(Women, WomenAdmin)
```

Now, feel free to personalize everything to your needs, but these are the basics of what you are looking for in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use TabularInline for selecting women in Excerpt model

```
class ExcerptInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Women.excerpt.through
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = True

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True


class ExcerptAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['start_time', 'end_time']
    inlines = [ExcerptInline]

class WomenAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
```

> finally add

```
admin.site.register(Women, WomenAdmin)
admin.site.register(Excerpt, ExcerptAdmin)
```

Comment: How would this get configured in the admin? I'm coming up with a 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable error.

Comment: admin.site.register(Women, WomenAdmin)
    admin.site.register(Excerpt, ExcerptAdmin)